# Diffrent x values while using multiple y-axis in achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a lineChart with two y axis and two lines. 
My lines have different setups for x values and y values.

When drawing up these lines the first line (x1,y1) looks as it should, but the second line (x2,y2) uses the x values from x1. Is there any way to solve this?

Below is a screenshot of my chart using the following code:

```
        double[] x1 = { 0,1,2,3,4,5 }; 
        double[] x2 = { 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 4, 6, 7 }; 
        double[] y1 = { 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 9}; 
        double[] y2 = {7, 1, 6, 3, 9, 2 };   
        XYSeries speedSeries = new XYSeries("speed",0);
        XYSeries accSeries = new XYSeries("acc",1);
        for(int i=0;i<x1.length;i++){
            speedSeries.add(x1[i], y1[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<x2.length;i++){ 
             accSeries.add(x2[i],y2[i]);
        }

        // Creating a dataset to hold each series
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); 
        dataset.addSeries(0,speedSeries);
        dataset.addSeries(1,accSeries);
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getRenderer();
        myChartSettings(renderer);
        mChartView2 = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, dataset, renderer);

Private void myChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
     renderer.setChartTitle("");
     renderer.setShowAxes(true);
     renderer.setShowLegend(false);
     renderer.setYAxisMin(0,0);
     renderer.setYAxisMax(10,0);
     renderer.setYAxisMin(0,1);
     renderer.setYAxisMax(10,1);
     renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT,0);
     renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.LEFT, 0);
     renderer.setXTitle("Time");
     renderer.setYTitle("",0);
     renderer.setShowGrid(true);
     renderer.setGridColor(Color.LTGRAY);
     renderer.setXLabels(7);
     renderer.setYLabels(7);
     renderer.setYTitle("", 1);
     renderer.setYAxisAlign(Align.RIGHT, 1);
     renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT, 1);  
     renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
     renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.GRAY);
     renderer.setInScroll(true);
     renderer.setYLabelsPadding(2);
     renderer.setYLabelsVerticalPadding(2);
     renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK); 
     renderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
     renderer.setYLabelsColor(0, Color.BLUE);
     renderer.setYLabelsColor(1, Color.RED);
 }

  public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getRenderer() { 
      XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(2);
      renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
      renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
      renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
      renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);


      XYSeriesRenderer r1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
      r1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      renderer.addSeriesRenderer(0,r1);
      XYSeriesRenderer r2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
      r2.setColor(Color.RED);
      renderer.addSeriesRenderer(1,r2);
      return renderer;
}
```

Was not able to upload images due to reputation points but the image can be seen in this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0m88v1yuc0appn/bild.JPG

Comment: What do you mean by "uses the x values from x1"? Do you mean the labels that are drawn? Please post a screenshot.

Comment: I have edited my question and shared a link with a screenshot

Comment: Thanks, I understand it. It seems like a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: That was what I thought, but good to get it confirmed. Thanks for your quick replys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug. I fixed it for you. You can download a version including this fix [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/).

Comment: Works perfectly! Can not thank you enough for your quick fix.